# Select value for one row base on other values in other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample data

```
RollNo   EnrollType   EnrollStart   EnrollEnd
---------------------------------------------
   1     Maths        1/Jan/2019    1/Jan/2020
   1     Science      1/Jun/2019    1/Jun/2020
   1     Social       2/Jun/2020    2/Jun/2021
```

In the above table, the first two row interprets that a student changed his enrolment type with in the initially assumed end date. So effectively the termination date of his first enrolment should be 1/Jun/2019.

The query that I am working on is to pull the data as mentioned above. So the extract should

```
1    maths      1/Jan/2019    1/Jun/2019
1    science    1/Jun/2019    1/Jun/2020
1    social     2/Jun/2020    2/Jun/2021
```

The query that I wrote is:

```
Select 
    rollno, enrolltype, enrollstart,
    case
       when (select count(*) from student 
             where enrollstart > s.enrollstart and enrollstart < s.enrollend) > 1 
          then
             (select top 1 enrollstart from student 
              where enrollstart > s.enrollstart and enrollstart < s.enrollend)
       else enrollend
    end
from 
    student s
```

The problem in production my database and the actual data is huge and this query doesn't seem to be efficient as it calls the subquery twice. Any better way to extract this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use `lead()/lag()`:

```
select rollno, enrollstart,
    case when enrollend > lead(enrollstart) over (partition by rollno order by enrollstart)
        then lead(enrollstart) over (partition by rollno order by enrollstart) 
        else enrollend
    end
from student;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just discovering that myself!